# Apache JMeter Issue With Keystore

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, keystore

I am trying to use Apache JMeter 3.3 to load test an internal website. I followed the Recording tutorial mentioned on the Jmeter site ([Apache JMeter HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html)). I have set the following in the JMeter **system.properties** file to use a keystore where I have a preloaded certificate for the internal website.

```
javax.net.ssl.keyStore
javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword
```

When I start the recorder, I get the following error in the log.

```
2018-02-06 21:18:57,036 INFO o.a.j.u.SSLManager: KeyStore created OK
2018-02-06 21:18:57,036 INFO o.a.j.u.SSLManager: Total of 1 aliases loaded OK from keystore
2018-02-06 21:19:02,620 INFO o.a.j.p.h.p.ProxyControl: [56429] Creating entry aus5.mozilla.org in C:\Software\Apache\JMeter\apache-jmeter-3.3\bin\proxyserver.jks
2018-02-06 21:19:08,735 ERROR o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [56429] Problem with keystore
java.io.IOException: Command failed, code: 1
keytool error (likely untranslated): java.security.cert.CertificateException: Fail to parse input stream

    at org.apache.jorphan.exec.KeyToolUtils.runNativeCommand(KeyToolUtils.java:338) ~[jorphan.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jorphan.exec.KeyToolUtils.keytool(KeyToolUtils.java:402) ~[jorphan.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jorphan.exec.KeyToolUtils.generateSignedCert(KeyToolUtils.java:299) ~[jorphan.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jorphan.exec.KeyToolUtils.generateHostCert(KeyToolUtils.java:276) ~[jorphan.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.ProxyControl.updateKeyStore(ProxyControl.java:1563) ~[ApacheJMeter_http.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.Proxy.getSSLSocketFactory(Proxy.java:333) [ApacheJMeter_http.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.Proxy.startSSL(Proxy.java:440) [ApacheJMeter_http.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.Proxy.run(Proxy.java:202) [ApacheJMeter_http.jar:3.3 r1808647]
2018-02-06 21:19:08,735 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [56429] Unable to negotiate SSL transaction, no keystore?
2018-02-06 21:19:08,735 ERROR o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [56429] Exception when processing sample
java.io.IOException: Unable to negotiate SSL transaction, no keystore?
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.Proxy.startSSL(Proxy.java:457) ~[ApacheJMeter_http.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.Proxy.run(Proxy.java:202) [ApacheJMeter_http.jar:3.3 r1808647]
2018-02-06 21:19:08,735 WARN o.a.j.p.h.p.Proxy: [56429] Exception while writing error
java.net.SocketException: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 0: socket write error
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:120) ~[?:1.8.0-internal]
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:143) ~[?:1.8.0-internal]
    at java.io.DataOutputStream.writeBytes(DataOutputStream.java:287) ~[?:1.8.0-internal]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.Proxy.writeErrorToClient(Proxy.java:574) [ApacheJMeter_http.jar:3.3 r1808647]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.Proxy.run(Proxy.java:267) [ApacheJMeter_http.jar:3.3 r1808647]
2018-02-06 21:21:04,050 INFO o.a.j.r.ResultCollector: Shutdown hook started
2018-02-06 21:21:04,065 INFO o.a.j.r.ResultCollector: Shutdown hook ended
```

Please advise why this strange keystore error is coming up.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you have clashing configurations, JMeter's `proxyserver.jks` 
 normally **doesn't require any additional** setup in *system.properties*, default configuration should work just fine.

Just in case you need to amend JMeter's keystore configuration for any reason be aware that it is controlled via the following properties:

```
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Test Script Recorder certificate configuration
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#proxy.cert.directory=<JMeter bin directory>
#proxy.cert.file=proxyserver.jks
#proxy.cert.type=JKS
#proxy.cert.keystorepass=password
#proxy.cert.keypassword=password
#proxy.cert.factory=SunX509
# define this property if you wish to use your own keystore
#proxy.cert.alias=<none>
# The default validity for certificates created by JMeter
#proxy.cert.validity=7
# Use dynamic key generation (if supported by JMeter/JVM)
# If false, will revert to using a single key with no certificate
#proxy.cert.dynamic_keys=true
```

The recommended way of overriding these properties is using *user.properties* file.

References:

- [Test Script Recorder certificate configuration](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#test_script_recorder_cert)
- [Configuring JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Recording HTTPS Traffic with JMeter's Proxy Server](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/recording-https-traffic-jmeters-proxy-server)